# College Interest rate by yearly payments

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

#### Problem

A loan of 20; 000, made at an interest rate of 6%, is to be repaid by level yearly payments
for 10 years, beginning 1 year after the loan is advanced. Just before making the seventh
repayment, the borrower wishes to repay the entire loan.

(a) If interest rates remain unchanged, what is the outstanding balance?
(b) Suppose interest rates have dropped to 5%. How much will the borrower have to pay if
the lender uses the lower interest rate to calculate the outstanding balance?

#### Progress

I use the compound interest to calculate, but I can't get the expected answer. Anyone can help?

Comment: For (b) you mean that the interest rate for the *past* seven years is replaced with 5%?

Comment: After  the sixth payment, the interest rate drop to 5%.

Comment: Then how should a change in future interest rates influence the current balance?